# Llamar a una Activity con Fragments desde otra Activity

Tags: android

He tratado de realizar un ejemplo simple para tablet.

Lo que realizo es: creo un `Activity` y por medio de un botón llamo a la `Activity 2`. Este `Activity 2`  contiene dos fragmentos, pero al invocarlo por medio del botón, me aparecen varios errores y no se a que se debe.

Adjunto el código que me arroja el logcat:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.example.ivan.teto/com.example.ivan.teto.ActividadListaOpciones}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2070)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4823)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.example.ivan.teto.ActividadListaOpciones.onCreate(ActividadListaOpciones.java:11)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4823) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.ivan.teto.ListaOpciones did not create a view.
at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4687)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
at com.example.ivan.teto.ActividadListaOpciones.onCreate(ActividadListaOpciones.java:11) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4823) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Este es el código fuente del `Activity` que tiene conflicto:

```
public class ActividadListaOpciones extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad_lista_opciones);
    }
}
```

Layout de `ActividadListaOpciones`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".ActividadListaOpciones"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/lista_opciones"
        android:name="com.example.ivan.teto.ListaOpciones"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        tools:layout="@layout/listaopciones"
        class="com.example.ivan.teto.ListaOpciones" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/lista_estudiante"
        android:name="com.example.ivan.teto.ListaEstudiante"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        tools:layout="@layout/listaestudiante"
        class="com.example.ivan.teto.ListaEstudiante" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity `ListaEstudiante` (Fragment 1):

```
public class ListaEstudiante extends Fragment {
    View rootView;

    public View onCreaView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listaestudiante, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Layout del Fragment 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hector, Jazmin, Santiago" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity `ListaOpciones.java` (Fragment 2) :

```
public class ListaOpciones extends Fragment {
        View rootView;
    public View onCreaView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
            rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.listaopciones,container,false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Layout Fragment 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hola Mundo"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Archivo `Manifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ivan.teto">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ActividadListaOpciones"
        android:label="@string/menu_opciones">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVIDADLISTAOPCIONES" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hector, para poder darte mejor ayuda deberías también agregar los layouts ya que el problema ocurre al tratar de abrir los layouts y el codigo de los fragments no solo el activity.

Comment: Sería interesante ver los onCreateView() de tus Fragment, seguramente el error esté ahí

Comment: Hola ya edite la pregunta y añadí el codigo faltante gracias por su ayuda..Cabe aclarar que estoy trabajando en Andriod studio la ultima version baja linux...Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mirando tu código me he dado cuenta de que tienes métodos clave mal escritos y supongo que seria por el copia/pega al introducir en la pregunta el código, pero por si acaso, quiero que lo tengas en cuenta.

En tu código java de los fragmentos, llamas a un método llamado `onCreaView()` y ese método no existe. **Te has colado al escribir el nombre del método, por que se escribe `onCreateView()`.**

Arreglando ese pequeño despiste la app te funcionará sin problemas.

He probado tu código antes de contestarte porque pensaba que el error era provocado por otro código, pero cambiando eso, no me ha dado ningún problema al ejecutar.

Mira a ver si es eso y si lo es, tranquilo, los despistes como estos nos pasan a todo, si no, déjame un comentario para intentar ayudarte.

¡¡Suerte con tu app!!

Comment: Gracias Vicky efectivamente ese era el error, muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada Hector, me alegro que fuese esa la solución. De todas formas, ya que veo que eres nuevo, quería avisarte que, en caso de que en un comentario vaya destinado a algún usuario, utilices @HectorValencia para que le llegue la notificación. Si es un comentario en su propia contestación, no hace falta, pero si el comentario es en tu pregunta o en alguna otra, es una buena opción. :)